# How to `onclick` using `Select` so that I can call a function to get the id and to pass to windows location?

Tags: html, asp.net

How to `onclick` using `Select` so that I can call a function to get the id and to pass to windows location?

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="createAppointmentContact" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select class="form-control select2contact" id="createAppointmentContact" onClick="myFunction()"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Ignore the previous edit of this comment, I didn't see you were using asp.net

Comment: @MilesZew , call the id eg. http://formaid.sshitechss.com/Pages/FinanceInvoiceEditNew.aspx?id=1011